# Entity Manager remove is slow for first instance

Tags: performance, jpa, optimization, entitymanager

I have list of entities which I loop over and call Entity Manager remove one after the other.

I found that the method is performing slow.

On profiling, I found that the first call to `em.remove` takes lot of time while the next ones happens very quickly.

I am not sure, why the first remove is slow and what can be done to improvise it.

Comment: the actual remove call with most JPA providers does very little; it should delay the delete statement until the transaction commits or is flushed, so this is likely more to do with your container and it lazily initializing the EntityManager context into the wrapper on the first call instead of upfront in your method. You haven't mentioned your container at all, or even if this is the first call by the application (after deployment) or a reoccurring cost on each method call.

Comment: @Chris: Thanks for your comment! I am on Tomcat container...this issue is re-occurring on each call. This delete op is like cascade delete

Comment: Tomcat or TomEE with container managed persistence? You'd have to turn on logging, and maybe even step into the em.remove method to see why it might be taking longer and point at what might be done. Try turning on your JPA provider logging as well as maybe some config setting is causing some initial overhead.